# export png file embedded in blender files

Tags: uv, export, image, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to make a model for unity. There is no problem with the model, but the textures of the model are embedded in the blender file. how can i parse this png file from blender file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean export the PNG?

If so, you can do Image > Save As:

[image]

If you mean something else, please add more details in your post or comment on this answer what you mean.

Comment: oh! Thanks for this answer. I don't understand why I didn't think of it. anyway. you saved my life. good day!

Comment: Glad it helped!